# Условия использования Java

Tags: java, лицензирование

Правильно ли я понимаю, что для рядовых разработчиков по сути нет ограничений на использование Java? То есть все обязанности по лицензированию ложатся сугубо на разработчика платформы (например, на Google, если речь идёт об Android). А у разработчика будут какие-то обязанности только если он одновременно является и автором платформы (например, какое-то встраиваемое решение, когда все части системы разрабатываются одной организацией). Если же JRE уже есть под требуемую платформу, то разработчик может свободно под неё разрабатывать на Java (какие-то ограничения могут быть уже наложены лишь разработчиком платформы, но не самой Oracle). Верно?

Дополнительный вопрос: OpenJDK распространяется под GPL. Значит ли это, что если разработчик платформы будет использовать OpenJDK (и откроет все изменения, необходимые для адаптации под свою платформу), то он ничего Oracle не должен? Насколько я понимаю, именно поэтому Google планирует переход Android на OpenJDK (чтобы ничего не платить Oracle, несмотря на то, что его решение встраиваемое, а не для "компьютеров общего назначения").

И наконец: может ли автор программы на Java распространять вместе с ней JRE (при условии, что JRE уже существует под данную платформу), чтобы пользователю было не обязательно устанавливать Java самостоятельно? Или единственный вариант действий при отсутствии установленной JRE (и если по каким-то причинам невозможно использовать OpenJDK, который по идее может распространять абсолютно свободно) - отправить пользователя на сайт Oracle?

Comment: В любом случае можно просто не трепаться особо о том, что используешь, и никто не обратит внимания есть лицензия, нет лицензии.

Comment: Так то оно так, однако если вы поставляете кому-нибудь программу на Java, то факт её использования будет очевиден.

Comment: Пользователь, если не хочет лишиться замечательной программы, тоже пусть помалкивает

Comment: По-моему, разработчик платформы должен соблюдать GPL, если использует исходники open jdk, и пройти тесты из [TCK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_Compatibility_Kit), если хочет называть свое творение java-совместимым (андроид, например, не совместим). Прикладной программист может пользоваться стандартной библиотекой (там GPL с linking exception для этого). Если надо распространять приложение вместе с Oracle JRE, то есть условия в [лицензии](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html) (раздел D). Ну или в стороно Azul Zulu посмотреть.

Comment: Я реализовал серию на Java (Oracle JRE)- demo можно скачать перед покупкой. Лицензия не ограничивает использование JRE в составе поставляемого кода. [Java SE FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/faqs-jsp-136696.html)

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы ничего не платили Oracle и никаких соглашений с ней не заключали?

Answer (score 1):

OpenJDK распространяется не под *GPL*, а под *GPL with classpath exception*. Таким образом, когда вы пишите свой код, который использует код стандартной библиотеки, условия *GPL* на ваш код не распространяются и вы вольны вибирать лицензию своего кода совершенно свободно. *GPL* with classpath exception близок к *LGPL*. Разница между ними в том, что *LGPL* разрешает другим изучать и модифицировать ваш код, а *GPL with classpath exception* не добавляет эту возможность, оставляя её на усмотрение авторов стороннего кода. Таким образом *GPL with classpath exception* лучше подходит для написания коммерческого программного обеспечения.